# Tags are spilling over to ads

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The tags are currently out of control. On Internet Explorer 10, Windows 7 Professional you can see the tags spilling over onto the ads. I did this while not logged in and I tried some other *.stackexchange.com sites but only this site had the tags over the ads on the right. Could not reproduce in Chrome, have not tried Firefox.

[image: Tags are OUT OF CONTROL]

Comment: No repro, Chrome 29, Firefox 24, Firefox 25; repro, IE10, Windows 8

Comment: Why anyone would expect IE to display something properly is beyond me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pushed a fix for this to dev server. It will be on live after our next production build(within 24hrs)